# Find a basis for the subspace X that is the intersection of subspaces V and W

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> a) Explain what is meant by a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> Describe the possible subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> Let v = (1,1,1) and w = (2,−1,1), and define two subspaces V and W of
> $\mathbb{R}^3$ as: V ={u : u.v=0} W ={u : u.w=0}
>
> b) Find a basis for the subspace X that is the intersection of
> subspaces V and W.

**ATTEMPT**

I think I have defined a subspace correctly

a) The subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a non-empty subset S that contains the 0 vector that has the following properties:

1. $u,v \in S \implies u + v \in S$
2. $u \in S, \lambda \in \mathbb{R} : \lambda u \in S$

And I believe the possible subspaces of $\mathbb{R^3}$ can be described as a line through the origin.

My confusion comes from the second part, what elements does $V \cap W$ contain? the sets V and W describe sets that contain the elements that contain vectors that are perpendicular to (1,1,1) and (2,-1,1) respectively. How do I approach the question from here?

Comment: $\mathbb R^3$  also has two dimensional subspaces (not to mention $\mathbb R^3$ itself and the zero element.).

Comment: Note too that you never finished the second part of your definition of a subspace.  The intersection of two subsets  $A,B$ is the set of elements which are in both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: $(2,1,-3)$ is orthogonal to $v$ and $w$. Dimension considerations show that $V \cap W$ is spanned by this single vector.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm familiar with what intersection means. My question wasn't clearly written. I've updated it so that it makes more sense. I have also updated my definition thanks for pointing that out :) @lulu

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So essentially the question wants me to find the set of vectors that are perpendicular to v and w? because this would also be perpendicular to u?

Comment: The title doesn't match the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b) Since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is an euclidean space, then both $V$ and $W$ have dimension 2. (2,1,-3) is perpendicular to $v$ and $w$ so $V \cap W$is nonzero. Hence $V \cap W$ is of dimension either 1 or 2. If its dimension is 2, then $V=W$ and so $vect(v)=vect(w)$ wich is a contradiction because the family $\{v,w\}$ is free. So $V \cap W$ has dimension 1 and has basis any one of its nonzero elements for example {(2,1,-3)}.